# Front End Entry Form - File/asset field not saving when ajax submitted

Tags: assets, ajax, frontend, frontend-form, assets-field

I have a front end entry form which submits and saves fine when not using ajax.
But when i do submit via ajax the text fields etc save fine but the file/assets field will not.

I have stripped it right back for testing but still not saving the file on ajax submit.
I have even made the logged in user a full admin for testing purposes.

My Form:

```
<form method="post" id="applicationForm" class="sform2" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
    {{ hiddenInput('sectionId', '3') }}
    {{ hiddenInput('enabled', '1') }}
    {{ hiddenInput('entryId', '159') }}      

    <label for="nameAccountIsHeldIn" class="col-12 col-form-label">Name account is held in</label>

    <input type="text" name="fields[nameAccountIsHeldIn]" class="form-control" id="nameAccountIsHeldIn" value="">

    <input type="file" name="fields[accounts][]" class="form-control" id="accounts" multiple>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>        

</form>
```

js:

```
$('.sform2').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    startAlerts();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var url = $(this).attr("action");

    console.log($(this));
    console.log(data);


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $(this).serialize() ,
        dataType : 'json', // changing data type to json
        success: function (response) { // here I'm adding data as a parameter which stores the response
            console.log(response); // instead of alert I'm changing this to console.log which logs all the response in console.
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer after much time spent on it.

The `$(this).serialize()` loses the file input - and can't submit.

Updated ajax submit to

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: new FormData(this) ,
    dataType : 'json', // changing data type to json
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,        
    success: function (response) { // here I'm adding data as a parameter which stores the response
        console.log(response); // instead of alert I'm changing this to console.log which logs all the response in console.
    }
});
```